# Regex expression to search upto nested level

Tags: c#, regex

How to search search string upto nested level using Regex expression

Like say: I have string like

```
var str = "samir patel {samirpatel@test1.com{sam@somedomain.com}}";
```

Out put should be sam@somedomain.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply use this pattern:

```
{([^{}]*)}
```

This will match any string like `{some content}` which does not contain any other group like `{some content}`. You can test this [here](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%7B%28%5B%5E%7B%7D%5D%2a%29%7D&input=samir%20patel%20%7Bsamirpatel%40test1.com%7Bsam%40somedomain.com%7D%7D).

You can capture this using:

```
var str = "samir patel {samirpatel@test1.com{sam@somedomain.com}}";
var regex = new Regex("{([^{}]*)}");
var matches = regex.Matches(str);
var output = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
// output == "sam@somedomain.com"
```

Or more simply:

```
var str = "samir patel {samirpatel@test1.com{sam@somedomain.com}}";
var output = Regex.Match(str, "{([^{}]*)}").Groups[1].Value; 
// output == "sam@somedomain.com"
```

Comment: This gives out put like {sam@somedomain.com}. thanks for getting upto this level. But how to remove brackets. I requires output like sam@somedomain.com

Comment: The first group is the content without the brackets. See my updated answer.

Comment: Wow this worked. Thank you. Marking as answer.

Can you pls give one more hint ? What to use if I have <> brackets instead of {} 

like "samir patel <samirpatel@test1.com<sam@somedomain.com>>"

Comment: @Nijesh Do you want that in the same pattern or in a different pattern? in other words what should the output be if the input is `samir patel <samirpatel@test1.com{sam@somedomain.com}>`?

Comment: In same pattern. output should be same "sam@somedomain.com"

i.e. if input is "samir patel <samirpatel@test1.com<sam@somedomain.com>>"

output should be sam@somedomain.com

It should find most inner string from <>

Comment: @Nijesh Then the pattern `[<{]([^<>{}]*)[>}]` should work, but it's a bit strange. It treats `<` / `{` and `>` / `}` as interchangeable, so e.g. if input is `a{b<c}>`, output will be `c`. Hopefully that's okay for your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

You could get this result using `(?<=\{)[^{}]*(?=\})`, assuming a language other than JavaScript. In C#, for example, that's

```
result = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=\{)[^{}]*(?=\})").Value;
```

If you're using JavaScript, use `\{([^{}]*)\}` and access `$1` for the match result:

```
var myregexp = /\{([^{}]*)\}/;
var match = myregexp.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
    result = match[1];
}
```

Comment: I used following code and getting null in output


var regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\{)[^{}]*(?=\})");
var matches = regex.Matches(strFromEmail);